# Transaction deadlocked SqlMembershipProvider.CreateUser()

Tags: c#, asp.net

We run a small website where We use the standard SqlMembershipProvider and we have a standard CreateUserWizard.

We got an unhandled Exception:

Transaction (Process ID XX) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

The stack trace is

System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.**CreateUser**(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)

System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.**AttemptCreateUser**()

Any Idea how to fix this?

There SQL Query is the standard thing:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_CreateUser]
    @ApplicationName                        nvarchar(256),
    @UserName                               nvarchar(256),
    @Password                               nvarchar(128),
    @PasswordSalt                           nvarchar(128),
    @Email                                  nvarchar(256),
    @PasswordQuestion                       nvarchar(256),
    @PasswordAnswer                         nvarchar(128),
    @IsApproved                             bit,
    @CurrentTimeUtc                         datetime,
    @CreateDate                             datetime = NULL,
    @UniqueEmail                            int      = 0,
    @PasswordFormat                         int      = 0,
    @UserId                                 uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ApplicationId uniqueidentifier
    SELECT  @ApplicationId = NULL

    DECLARE @NewUserId uniqueidentifier
    SELECT @NewUserId = NULL

    DECLARE @IsLockedOut bit
    SET @IsLockedOut = 0

    DECLARE @LastLockoutDate  datetime
    SET @LastLockoutDate = CONVERT( datetime, '17540101', 112 )

    DECLARE @FailedPasswordAttemptCount int
    SET @FailedPasswordAttemptCount = 0

    DECLARE @FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart  datetime
    SET @FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = CONVERT( datetime, '17540101', 112 )

    DECLARE @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount int
    SET @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = 0

    DECLARE @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart  datetime
    SET @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = CONVERT( datetime, '17540101', 112 )

    DECLARE @NewUserCreated bit
    DECLARE @ReturnValue   int
    SET @ReturnValue = 0

    DECLARE @ErrorCode     int
    SET @ErrorCode = 0

    DECLARE @TranStarted   bit
    SET @TranStarted = 0

    IF( @@TRANCOUNT = 0 )
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        SET @TranStarted = 1
    END
    ELSE
        SET @TranStarted = 0

    EXEC dbo.aspnet_Applications_CreateApplication @ApplicationName, @ApplicationId OUTPUT

    IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = -1
        GOTO Cleanup
    END

    SET @CreateDate = @CurrentTimeUtc

    SELECT  @NewUserId = UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE LOWER(@UserName) = LoweredUserName AND @ApplicationId = ApplicationId
    IF ( @NewUserId IS NULL )
    BEGIN
        SET @NewUserId = @UserId
        EXEC @ReturnValue = dbo.aspnet_Users_CreateUser @ApplicationId, @UserName, 0, @CreateDate, @NewUserId OUTPUT
        SET @NewUserCreated = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @NewUserCreated = 0
        IF( @NewUserId <> @UserId AND @UserId IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
            SET @ErrorCode = 6
            GOTO Cleanup
        END
    END

    IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = -1
        GOTO Cleanup
    END

    IF( @ReturnValue = -1 )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = 10
        GOTO Cleanup
    END

    IF ( EXISTS ( SELECT UserId
                  FROM   dbo.aspnet_Membership
                  WHERE  @NewUserId = UserId ) )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = 6
        GOTO Cleanup
    END

    SET @UserId = @NewUserId

    IF (@UniqueEmail = 1)
    BEGIN
        IF (EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM  dbo.aspnet_Membership m WITH ( UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK )
                    WHERE ApplicationId = @ApplicationId AND LoweredEmail = LOWER(@Email)))
        BEGIN
            SET @ErrorCode = 7
            GOTO Cleanup
        END
    END

    IF (@NewUserCreated = 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Users
        SET    LastActivityDate = @CreateDate
        WHERE  @UserId = UserId
        IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ErrorCode = -1
            GOTO Cleanup
        END
    END

    INSERT INTO dbo.aspnet_Membership
                ( ApplicationId,
                  UserId,
                  Password,
                  PasswordSalt,
                  Email,
                  LoweredEmail,
                  PasswordQuestion,
                  PasswordAnswer,
                  PasswordFormat,
                  IsApproved,
                  IsLockedOut,
                  CreateDate,
                  LastLoginDate,
                  LastPasswordChangedDate,
                  LastLockoutDate,
                  FailedPasswordAttemptCount,
                  FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart,
                  FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount,
                  FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart )
         VALUES ( @ApplicationId,
                  @UserId,
                  @Password,
                  @PasswordSalt,
                  @Email,
                  LOWER(@Email),
                  @PasswordQuestion,
                  @PasswordAnswer,
                  @PasswordFormat,
                  @IsApproved,
                  @IsLockedOut,
                  @CreateDate,
                  @CreateDate,
                  @CreateDate,
                  @LastLockoutDate,
                  @FailedPasswordAttemptCount,
                  @FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart,
                  @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount,
                  @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart )

    IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = -1
        GOTO Cleanup
    END

    IF( @TranStarted = 1 )
    BEGIN
        SET @TranStarted = 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END

    RETURN 0

Cleanup:

    IF( @TranStarted = 1 )
    BEGIN
        SET @TranStarted = 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

    RETURN @ErrorCode

END
```

Thanks!

Comment: Transaction deadlocks are not common in a "small website" where one wouldn't expect a lot of competition for resources. see if this post can shed more light about the problem you are facing: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/e0210b4f-61c4-41f3-a573-c5fe7ac33b5e

Comment: competition for resources in my opinion does not have to do with the traffic but with how badly is the webpage programmed.
I will try to get those graphics that the thread talks about.

Answer (score 1):

Did someone have the table open in SQL Server Management Studio in edit mode ie: Table Lock?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the @UserId to a new GUID and it will work.

```
set @User = NEWID();
```